# Question mark icon at web reference in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know what does the icon shown below mean? I am maintaining legacy code and found this web reference with that question mark. The web reference works just perfect, I am able to update it and everything seems to be working fine but the question mark annoys me.

[image: Question mark icon at web reference in Visual Studio 2015]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer: that icon is added by Ankh plugin. I just disabled the Ankh plugin and the icon dissapeared.